# Add HTML module to skin automatically - DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Is there a way to add an HTML module to a skin by default? Right now, I have a `<div id="ContentPane" runat="server"></div>` and when a user creates a page, it just has a blank area that allows them to add modules.

Is there a way to automatically insert the HTML module, so when a page is created, the user doesn't have to manually add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having the user's create a page using the Default Template in DNN (found in the page creation settings), but other than that, no, it isn't possible.

You could possibly write some custom code in the skin that would automatically create one if one didn't exist, but I would find that really annoying as a site administrator if I came across that.